# How can I get the responsePage from a RequestCycle in Wicket 1.5?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

In Wicket 1.4 I used my own `WebRequestCycle` to store the page in the session when it was detached - in order to implement a 'back' link.

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
    @Override public void onDetach(RequestCycle cycle) {
        squirrelAwayPreviousPage(cycle);
    }
    private void squirrelAwayPreviousPage(RequestCycle cycle) {
        Page responsePage = cycle.getResponse();
        if (responsePage != null)
            ((MySession) getSession()).setPreviousPage(responsePage);
    }
});
```

Now in Wicket 1.5 `WebRequestCycle` has gone, and I'm supposed to use a `RequestCycleListener` in its place.

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
    @Override public void onDetach(RequestCycle cycle) {
        squirrelAwayPreviousPage(cycle);
    }
    private void squirrelAwayPreviousPage(RequestCycle cycle) {
        Page responsePage = **cycle.getResponsePage()**;
        if (responsePage != null)
            ((MySession) getSession()).setPreviousPage(responsePage);
    }
});
```

But `RequestCycle` doesn't have a `getReponsePage()`. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the migration guide:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/RequestCycle+in+Wicket+1.5 (Tracking requested and response pages)

Comment: Obviously the page's content or the functionality of the mentioned class `RequestLoggerRequestCycleListener` has changed in the meantime. The source code does not even contain the word "page". If anyone could come up with a little bit more info, I'd be very happy.

Comment: The class `RequestLoggerRequestCycleListener` was never mentioned... what's your actual problem? Please open a new question if your question is not related to this problem/solution.